# What am I doing wrong with xpath?

Tags: php, xpath

test.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <span> hello Joe</span>
        <span> hello Bob</span>
        <span> hello Gundam</span>
        <span> hello Corn</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP file

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("test.html");

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$retrieve_data = $xpath->evaluate("//span");

echo $retrieve_data->item(1);
var_dump($retrieve_data->item(1));
var_dump($retrieve_data);
```

I am trying to use xPath to find the spans and then echo it, but it seems I cannot echo it. I tried dumping it to see if is evaluating properly, and I am not sure what does this output mean:

```
object(DOMElement)#4 (0) { } 
object(DOMNodeList)#7 (0) { }
```

What does the `#4` and `#7` mean and what does the parenthesis mean; What is does the syntax mean?

Update: 
This is the error I get when I try to `echo $retrieve_data;` and `$retrieve_data->item(1);`

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but there are PHP DOM libraries that allow querying objects the jQuery way that feels much more natural to me than XPath. I *hate* XPath. [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) uses the PHP DOM - examples [here](http://phpquery-library.blogspot.com/); [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is string based but also very nice.

Comment: I don't know PHP's XPath syntax, but have you tried "//span/text()"? Currently, you're selecting the elements, but you want to output the text inside the elements.

Comment: @chris_l It's not **PHP's** XPath Syntax. It's just XPath. Same in any other language, just that PHP only supports XPath 1.0. @Doug your question has nothing to do with XPath. You are asking how to read standard `var_dump` output.

Comment: @Pekka I will take a look at SimpleHTMLDOM, but I still want to solve this problem.

Comment: @Gordon: Ok, but the API around it is different enough, that I can't tell for sure, how it will handle the result (i. e. will it automatically extract the text content from an element...)

Comment: @Gordon I think the var_dump question was in addition to my xPath question.

Comment: @chris_l I'm not sure what you mean by that? PHP's DOM extension is an implementation of the [W3C DOM Interface](http://www.w3.org/DOM/).

Comment: @Gordon: That may be true (and it's part of what I don't know about PHP's XPath API). But XPath can not only be used to navigate W3C DOM. For example, there are other APIs (like Dom4j), which are only similar to W3C DOM, but can still be used with XPath. Also, I don't think, that `var_dump` is part of W3C DOM. If it was implemented to print the `string-value` of nodes, there would be no need for using `text()` (the `string-value` for an element returns the concatenation of descendant text nodes).

Comment: @chris_l [`var_dump`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is a native PHP function and completely unrelated to DOM and XPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to output text inside span you can use textContent property:

> echo $retrieve_data->item(1)->textContent;

Comment: I was trying echo `$retrieve_data->item(1);` earlier. Should that not echo the span html? Also, where can I find the documentation for the textContent part? I did not know you can do that.

Comment: Just like VdesmedT said below item(1) is not a string - it's Node object which may include a lot of stuff besides text and name. Base class for all nodes is described (with all available properties) here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

Answer (score 3):

```
$xpath->evaluate("//span");
```

returns a typed result if possible or a [`DOMNodeList`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) containing all nodes matching the given XPath expression. In your case, it returns a `DOMNodeList`, because your XPath evaluates to four [`DOMElements`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php), which are specialized [`DOMNodes`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php). Understanding the Node concept when working with any XML, regardless in what language, is crucial.

```
echo $retrieve_data->item(1);
```

cannot work, because [`DOMNodeList::item`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) returns a `DOMNode` and more specifically a `DOMElement` in your case. You cannot `echo` objects of any kind in PHP, if they do not implement the [`__toString()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) method. `DOMElement` doesnt. Neither does `DOMNodeList`. Consequently, you get the fatal error that the object could not be converted to string.

To get the DOMElement's values, you either read their [`nodeValue`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue) or [`textContent`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent).

Some DOM examples by me: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A208809+dom

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output the XML (or HTML rather), try:

```
echo $doc->saveXML( $retrieve_data->item(1) );
```

BTW, the `DOMNodeList`, that is the result of your query, is zero base indexed, so the first item would be `0`. But perhaps you knew this already.

Answer (score 1):

your item is as DOMNode object, echo its nodeValue property might helps

Comment: I have no idea what you juts said. What is its nodeValue? Like item(1)?

Comment: echo $retrieve_data->item(1)->nodeValue;